# Best way to dynamically add elements in Angular side by side

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components

I am creating an app which has an API that returns different number of objects in an array depending on the variable that I send him. Depending on how many objects are returned I want to draw that many circles side by side in a row, max 10 circles in one row. Each returned object is carrying info about circle color, id, name. So, if the API returns 20 objects I want to draw 20 circles ( 2 rows), color them in appropriate color which comes with the object, assign them an ID in HTML and a name. What is the best way to dynamically add elements in Angular depending on the size of the returned array from an API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use template injection:

```
<div *ngFor='let item of itemsArray' 
     [id]='item.id_key' 
     [ngStyle]="{'background-color': item.color}">
{{ item.name }}
</div>
```

Or you could use the [renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) class, and dynamically `createElement()` and `appendChild()`.

Both approaches are valid, it comes down to personal preference.